# Set target=“_blank” and rel=“nofollow, noindex, noreferrer” to all links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman

There seems to be a way how to set external links to no-follow per default to avoid losing important link juice through do-follow links to external websites it would be really good and make things much easier if we had automated that.

I have a lot of articles/blog posts in markdown that is being generated upon middleman deployment. It’s a hassle to manually add {:target="_blank" rel="nofollow, noindex, noreferrer"} at the end of each link within the text.

I've researched that I can add

```
<meta name =”robots” content=”index”>
```

but I'm guessing there must be a more granular approach is to include the noFollow tag for individual links.

Is there a way to set link attributes in config.rb so that it's set like below?

```
target="_blank" rel="nofollow, noindex, noreferrer"
```

Comment: Are you using RedCarpet to render your MD? If so, you can specify the [link attributes](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#darling-i-packed-you-a-couple-renderers-for-lunch)

Comment: wrong notation: no comma needed in rel values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good approach here is to create your own helper-method under `app/helpers` and use it in your views

Smth like:

```
def link_to_new_window(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = {}, &block)
  html_options[:target] = '_blank'
  html_options[:rel] = 'nofollow, noindex, noreferrer'
  helper.link_to(name, options, html_options, &block)
end
```

**UPD**
I see that you're using `middleman`. Don't have much experience with it, but you can decorate like this pretty-much any helper method

Note the `helper` call, it'll allow you to use Rails helpers when they not explicitly included

To decorate the original method you can do:

```
module LinkToWithNewWindow
  def link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = {}, &block)
    html_options[:target] = '_blank'
    html_options[:rel] = 'nofollow, noindex, noreferrer'
    super(name, options, html_options, &block)
  end
end
::ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.prepend LinkToWithNewWindow
```

*Replace ActionView with the helper you use if needed*
But again, do it at your own risk

Comment: If I add the helper method like above - will I then need to change the link one by one in view like how you mentioned for usage in view? I have multiple links in md and if that's the case then it would be a hassle to go through one by one.

Comment: @nothingme it's better to update them one-by-one than have an implicit addition of this attributes for all the links. It should be as easy as one _find and replace_

But it's up to you, you can add a decorator for the helper. I'll update the answer with an example

Comment: @nothingme check out the last edit. I hope it'll help